Why is Kuf used (davka and not some other letter) to obscure God's names?
Elokim, Ka, Kel etc.
Almost nothing in Judaism is stem, certainly not when it comes to consistent choice of letters for a purpose like this.
Are there any sources regarding this?

I think it's because ק and ה are similar-looking letters.

@magicker72 Nice!
